# Converting np.nan pixels to transparent with GDAL

Tags: gdal, rasterio

I am attempting to create a mask layer of vegetation from aerial imagery of the soybean fields I work with. The code I am using is below. I am attempting to export the mask layer (exgMask) as a GeoTiff file, and that all works well. However, I would like to be able to convert pixels corresponding to no vegetation as transparent, instead of black (picture below code). I have looked through similar questions asked on this forum but I am having trouble translating the solutions to my own project. Is there a simple way to introduce transparent pixels?

```
import rasterio
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
from rasterio.plot import show
from rasterio.plot import show_hist
import rasterstats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from osgeo import gdal
import os

os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = r"C:\Users\nb47899\Anaconda3\envs\maturity\Library\share\proj"

#Read GeoTiff
fp = [file path to geotiff]
ds = gdal.Open(fp)
gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()
proj = ds.GetProjection()

r = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
g = ds.GetRasterBand(2)
b = ds.GetRasterBand(3)

r = r.ReadAsArray()
g = g.ReadAsArray()
b = b.ReadAsArray()

# Allow for 0 division in numpy
np.seterr(divide = 'ignore', invalid = 'ignore')

check = np.logical_or(r > 0, g > 0, b > 0)
exgMask = np.where(check, 2*(g/(r+g+b)) - r/(r+g+b) - b/(r+g+b) >=0.1, np.nan)
# show(exgMask)

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
driver.Register()
outds = driver.Create('ExgM01.tif', xsize = exgMask.shape[1],
                      ysize = exgMask.shape[0], bands = 1,
                      eType = gdal.GDT_Int16)
outds.SetGeoTransform(gt)
outds.SetProjection(proj)
outband = outds.GetRasterBand(1)
outband.WriteArray(exgMask)
outband.SetNoDataValue(np.nan)
outband.FlushCache()

outband = None
outds = None
```

[image: Masked layer in QGIS]

Comment: NaN is a float but you're writing an integer raster.  You need to call `outband.SetNoDataValue()` using whatever value corresponds to black in the actual output (`0`?)

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much!